# For a person who doesn't eat dairy are there any halachic or health issues with using a meaty pot to cook all food and drink?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, meat-and-milk, meat

If someone never eats dairy (and won't be sharing with people who do), is there any halachic problem with using a meaty pot to cook all their food?

Would the same apply to someone who eats meat, but only on Shabbos?

Comment: Are you asking if one can cook parve food in a meat pot? Most people do that don't they?

Comment: @mbloch Yes, that was the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know for non dairy eaters, there's still a prohibition of cooking fish together with meat to eat due to the of danger of contracting *Tzaraat* (skin disease).
Shulchan Aruch [Yoreh Deah 116:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.116.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> צריך ליזהר שלא לאכול בשר ודג ביחד, מפני שקשה לצרעת.
>   הגה: וכן אין לצלות בשר עם דג, משום ריחא

The Kaf Hachaim ([ibid 20](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.116.2?lang=bi&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.20.1&lang2=bi)) explains through the consensus of most Rabbinic authorities that one is allowed to use the same pot to cook meat, then clean the pot and then use it to cook fish as long as not cooked together. When fish is cooked together with meat one must wait 24 hours to use the pot.

> ך) ומיהו יכול לבשל בכלי של בשר ב"י תבשיל של דגים דאין פליטת כלים אוסרת מבשר לדגים או איפכא. או"ה כלל ט"ל דין כ"ו. רש"ל פכ"ה סי' ט' ט"ז סי' צ"ה סק"ג. כנה"ג בסי' זה בהגב"י או' י"ח. מנ"י על התו"ח כלל נ"ז או' א' לה"פ או' ג' בל"י או' ד' חכ"א שם בהגה. עדות ביהוסף סי' מ"ו. וכתב ודלא כחומרת הטור שכתב שיש ליחד כלים לדגים בפ"ע ולבשר בפ"ע יעו"ש. עיקרי הד"ט חי"ד סי' י"ד או' יו"ד. זכ"ל ח"ג או' קפ"ו. ומיהו סיים שם המנ"י ונוהגין להקל אם הוא נקי עכ"ל ור"ל אפי' לכתחלה. ומיהו אם בישלו בשר ודג ביחד כתבנו לעיל או' י"ג דיש להחמיר ואין לבשל באותה קדרה עד לאחר מעל"ע יעו"ש.

So it seems that with regards to those who abstain from eating meat during the week - though not Halachicly obliged - if it is not Neder related he may eat from a clean meaty pot his *pareve* foods